# Decompose a group $G$ into a normal subgroup $N$ and quotient group $Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, exact-sequence

1. If $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ and quotient group $Q$, so $$G/N=Q,$$ or $$N \to G \to Q$$

   > can we always decompose a group $G$ into a pair of data $(N,Q)$? Say $g \in G$, $g$ is isomorphic to $(n,q)$ with $n \in N$ and $q \in Q$?
2. How can we generic express $g_1 \cdot g_2 \in G$, in terms of 
   $$(n_1,q_1) \cdot (n_2,q_2)=(n', q') \in G?$$

> How do we write explicitly $$(n', q')$$
>   in terms of $n_1,q_1,n_2,q_2$ as directly as possible?

We may assume a finite group for simplicity. (A side question: How about a Lie group?)

Comment: Look into the theory of group extensions

Comment: In order to have a chance at this decomposition, a group must have a normal subgroup, so it can not be simple. Moreover, having fixed a normal subgroup, the question of whether you can decompose your group in the proposed way depends on the extension being split, which does not always happen.

Comment: Suppose that it splits, can we answer and simplify the question 2?

Answer (score 1):

One runs into a problem when trying to create a group isomorphism -- in particular, one runs into a problem in creating a homomorphism. Let $\varphi:N\times Q\to G$ be a function that we are trying to create as a group isomorphism.

First, we must identify "special" elements of $G$ that we can use to identify elements of $Q\equiv \{ gN = Ng | g\in G, N\triangleleft G \}$. To be formal, define an injective function $\psi:Q\to G$ such that (for $gN\in Q$), $\psi(gN)\in gN$; i.e., for every element in $Q$, we pick out a unique element in $G$ to identify that set.

Now, we can define (in accordance to 2.) $$\varphi(n, q) = n\cdot\psi(q)\ .$$ To define the inverse, we note that $\forall g\in G\exists! n\in N,q\in Q$ such that $g\in q$ and $g= \psi(q)\cdot n$ -- i.e., $g$ must be in some quotient set $q=hN$, identified with $h$, since the union of quotient sets contains all of $G$. Uniqueness follows from the fact that $g$ cannot exist in two distinct quotient sets, and $n=(\psi(q))^{-1}\cdot g$ is a unique definition. Now, with this decomposition, it is clear that the inverse $\varphi^{-1}(g)=\varphi^{-1}(\psi(q)\cdot n) = (n,q)$ is well-defined. Thus, $\varphi$ is a *set* isomorphism.

What remains to show is that we can make $\varphi$ a *group* isomorphism. For this, $\varphi$ must be a homomorphism: (for $q_0,q_1\in Q$ and $n_0, n_1\in N$):
\begin{align}
\varphi((n_0,q_0)\cdot (n_1,q_1)) &= \varphi(n_0\cdot n_1,q_0\cdot q_1) \\
&= n_0n_1\psi(q_0q_1) \\
&= n_0n_1\psi(q_0)\psi(q_1)\ .
\end{align}
For $\varphi$ to be a homomorphism, this must be equal to
$$
\varphi(n_0,q_0)\cdot \varphi(n_1,q_1) = n_0 \psi(q_0) n_1 \psi(q_1)\ .
$$
If this is true, then
\begin{align}
n_0n_1\psi(q_0)\psi(q_1) &= n_0 \psi(q_0) n_1 \psi(q_1) \\
n_1\psi(q_0) &= \psi(q_0) n_1\ .
\end{align}
Thus, we need to make our construction satisfy some commutation relation. Also, note that $qN=Nq$ does not mean that $nq=qn$, since we could have $nq=qn_0$ for $n\neq n_0\in N$. However, we if $N$ happens to also be in the center of $G$, $Z(G):=\{ g\in G | gh=hg\forall h\in G \}$, then $\varphi$ is a group isomorphism and $G\cong N\times Q$.

We have no choice for the $n$ argument in $\varphi$, but be may be able to choose $\psi$ in a clever way to make $\varphi$ a homomorphism. In particular, we want the image of $\psi$ to be contained in the centralizer of $N$, $C_G(N) = \{ g\in G | gn=ng\forall n\in N \}$. That is, if every element in the quotient group $Q$ is a set that contains an element in the centralizer of the normal group (in math-y terms, $\forall q\in Q:q\cap C_G(N)\neq \emptyset$), then we can construct a group isomorphism $\varphi:N\times Q\to G$ by identifying elements in $Q$ with elements in the centralizer $C_G(N)$.

At the end of the day, the problem in identifying $G$ with the tensor product $N\times Q$ is that the tensor product inherits some commuting properties that may not be present in $G$. Strictly speaking, I have not proved that there does not exist a group isomorphism, just that the "natural" function to identify elements in $N\times Q$ with elements in $G$ (which is a perfectly good *set* isomorphism) does not preserve the group properties. Also, I did not make any assumption on the finiteness of $G$, so this is all perfect valid for infinite groups and Lie groups.